# How to convert utf-8 values within a string to its correct character using python?

Tags: python

I would like to convert 'Lawrence_Warbasse_-_Dauphin%C3%A9_2013.JPG' to 'Lawrence_Warbasse_-_Dauphiné_2013.JPG' usig python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urllib` to decode this:

```
import urllib
url = 'Lawrence_Warbasse_-_Dauphin%C3%A9_2013.JPG'
print urllib.unquote(url).decode('utf8')
```

The output I get is:

```
Lawrence_Warbasse_-_Dauphiné_2013.JPG
```